# call html page with jquery-mobile in a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, browser-cache

I'm calling html5 page inside a iframe. To prevent the cache I call the page thus:

... not irelevant code...

```
<iframe  id="contentframe1" name="contentframe1" frameborder="0" scrolling="No"   src="" height="432" width="100%"> </iframe>
```

... not irelevant code

Javascript code for call html5+jquery-mobile page...

```
$("#contentframe1").attr('src',urlVista);
var d= new Date();      

var urlVista="usuarios/"+parent.parent.Nb_Global_usuario+"/aplicaciones/"+parent.parent.Nb_Global_aplicacion+"/appfiles/vistas/"+LinkTab[aux]+".html?"+d.toString();
```

How you can see i call this page with uncached mode.The problem:

In the html5+jQuery-Mobile page I have a multipage.

PageA calls PageB..correct!!

But when PageB does back button action the next error appear:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 0200%20(Hora%20de%20verano%20romance]')
```

The solution is remove uncached mode...but I need that the page load without cache.

any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the characters "("  , ")" , " " to nothing,
d=d.toString().replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(' ','');